# How to parse MICR line in java

Tags: java

Greetings!!

According to my requirement, I have to parse MICR line and populate the same in java. If anyone know of a JAVA API that will accurately parse the MICR line for the different components, please help me.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.
Vidya Bhushan.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: How will you give MICR input to JAVA ?

Comment: Have you tried to google at first?

Comment: @Umesh:I am not sure, but I assume, using MICR reader we can capture the raw data and think of parse it. Please provide your input if I am wrong.